# Amazon EC2 :- Not able to install Mariadb

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mariadb

I'm trying to install Mariadb in Amazon EC2 instance. I'm getting the below error while running `yum install mariadb mariadb-server`

```
file /etc/my.cnf from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.68-1.amzn2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-config-3:10.2.10-2.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
```

[image: The recommendation is to run amazon-linux-extras install lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 but even that is not working as my PHP version is 7.4. It returns Refusing because lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 could cause an invalid combination.]

The recommendation is to run `amazon-linux-extras install lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2` but even that is not working as my PHP version is 7.4. It returns `Refusing because lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 could cause an invalid combination.`

Comment: Can you try on fresh instance. I tried to repliacate, but there are no issues install php7.4 and mariadb-server on Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: @Marcin Yea. If nothing working I'll try on a new instance. It worked for PHP 7.2 and then I upgraded the PHP version to 7.4. There seems to be some compatibility issue.

Comment: I see. Its possible. I tried by install only php7.4.

Answer (score 0):

To go with php7.4 on Amazon Linux 2 you need to enable it first.

```
yum remove -y php php-* \ 
&& amazon-linux-extras disable php7.2 \
&& amazon-linux-extras enable php7.4 \
&& amazon-linux-extras install php7.4 \
&& yum clean all
```

About installing MariaDB on Amazon Linux 2, you can use the standard installation:

```
curl -sS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash -s -- --mariadb-server-version="mariadb:10.5.9" --os-type=rhel --os-version=8
```

Where the flags, will allow you to set the OS & Version to bypass the Amazon Linux naming convention.

```
--os-type=rhel 
--os-version=8
```